# I need to write a query which will give me a list of dates between two date ranges (start date and end date) IN ORACLE

Tags: c#, oracle

I need to write a query which will give me a list of dates between two date ranges (start 
date and end date) IN ORACLE .

For Example if my start date is 12/01/2003 and end Date is 12/31/2003. i need to generate 
my output as

```
Date
----
12/01/2003
12/02/2003
12/03/2003
12/04/2003
12/05/2003
12/06/2003
12/07/2003
12/08/2003
.
.
.
so on till 
12/31/2003
```

Answer (score 0):

For an Oracle specific solution you can use CONNECT BY

```
select to_date('12/01/2003','MM/DD/YYYY')+level-1
from dual
where to_date('12/01/2003','MM/DD/YYYY')+level-1 between '12/01/2003' and '12/31/2003'
connect by level <= 31
;
```

If you want a portable solution, you can try an older trick.

```
-- General purpose looper table.
-- Old trick I like to use for joining into queries to generate repeating sequences
-- without using more complex methods and it portable to other databases.

create table looper(i integer primary key) organization index;

begin
   for i in 1..100 loop
      insert into looper values(i);
   end loop;
end;
/
```

Use it like so:

```
select to_date('12/01/2003','MM/DD/YYYY')+looper.i-1
from looper
where to_date('12/01/2003','MM/DD/YYYY')+looper.i-1 between '12/01/2003' and '12/31/2003'
;
```

Other examples, give me next 12 months:

```
select add_months(sysdate, looper.i)
from looper
where looper.i <= 12
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will generate dates from a beginning date up to x days into the future (in this case I chose 31 days to give you the range in your example):

```
 SELECT TO_DATE('2003-11-30','YYYY-MM-DD')+ROWNUM n
 FROM   ( SELECT 1 column_name
          FROM   dual
          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 31
        )
```

But you could also use it to generate dates for an entire year:

```
 SELECT TO_DATE('2002-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD')+ROWNUM n
 FROM   ( SELECT 1 column_name
          FROM   dual
          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 365
        )
```

This is my favorite way to generate dates, since it is very simple, requires no tables, no procedures, no loops, no variables, etc. So it can easily be nested within other queries, joined to, etc.

Of course a drawback with this method is you need to know exactly how many days are in your range (for example if you want the dates for a leap year you must put level 366).

Also remember that the "start date" does not get included in the list.